# Get variable from Component A in Component B when it gets reasigned in Angular 9

Tags: angular

I have a slider component that assigns a `currentSlide` variable every time the slider items move.
It looks like this:

```
export class CarouselComponent implements OnInit {

  currentSlide = 0;

  onPreviousClick() {
    const previous = this.currentSlide - 1;
    this.currentSlide = previous < 0 ? this.slides.length - 1 : previous;
    console.log("previous clicked, new current slide is: ", this.currentSlide);
  }

}
```

Based in the `currentSlide` I want to display some changing information in the parent component.
How can I receive this same variable in a parent component every time it changes?

Comment: Child to parent communication is done via `@Output` event emitters in Angular.

Comment: refer https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event & https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-interacts-with-child-via-local-variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `@output` to emit value from `child` to `parent` component.

this is how you should do it :

```
  @Output('myOutputVal') myOutputVal = new EventEmitter(); 



onPreviousClick() {
    const previous = this.currentSlide - 1;
    this.currentSlide = previous < 0 ? this.slides.length - 1 : previous;
    console.log("previous clicked, new current slide is: ", this.currentSlide);
    this.myOutputVal.emit(this.currentSlide);
  }
```

then in `parent` component  you should catch the `emitted` value as below :

in `parent.html` :

```
<app-child (myOutputVal)="readOutputValueEmitted($event)"></app-child>
```

in `parent.ts` file :

```
readOutputValueEmitted(val){
    this.valueFromChild = val;
  }
```

Working demo :

> [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-output-subject)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you want to define the variable, you could use @Input or @Output of Angular directives. You can also combine the two.

Take a look at the documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inputs-outputs

---

### @Input

Use Input to hand a variable over to a child component. The child component can change the variable and changes are backpropagated to the parent.

Child Component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core'; // First, import Input
export class ItemDetailComponent {
  @Input() item: string; // decorate the property with @Input()
}
```

Child Template:

```
<p>
  Today's item: {{item}}
</p>
```

Parent Template:

```
<app-item-detail [item]="currentItem"></app-item-detail>
```

Parent Component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  currentItem = 'Television';
}
```

---

### @Output

Output emits an event from the child that the parent can set a listener to. You can use it to catch any changes in the variable.

Child Component

```
export class ItemOutputComponent {

  @Output() newItemEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();

  addNewItem(value: string) {
    this.newItemEvent.emit(value);
  }
}
```

Child Template:

```
<label>Add an item: <input #newItem></label>
<button (click)="addNewItem(newItem.value)">Add to parent's list</button>
```

Parent Template:

```
<app-item-output (newItemEvent)="addItem($event)"></app-item-output>
```

Parent Component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4'];

  addItem(newItem: string) {
    this.items.push(newItem);
  }
}
```